# Why doesn't Jupyter notebook command open notebook?

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When I write `jupyter notebook` in terminal it doesn't open notebook, it opens Jupyter tree. What can be the problem?

Comment: are you using Anaconda?

Comment: no, I am not using Anaconda

Comment: what happens when you run `jupyter-notebook.exe` (wherever it is located)

Comment: I couldn't find that file

Comment: how did you install jupyter? `pip install jupyter`? If so it should be in your Scripts Folder (by default) of where you downloaded this version of Python.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu

Comment: Okay. Question still stands I guess... How did you install jupyter?

Comment: using `pip install jupyter`

Answer (score 0):

The command you give should open Jupyter in the filesystem view first. You then navigate from there to a notebook and double-click that, which will open the notebook in a new browser tab.

Comment: no, it doesn't open in the file system it opens in browser, but opens Jupyter tree doesn't start Jupyter process

Answer (score 0):

**Question**: When I write `jupyter notebook` in terminal it doesn't open notebook, it opens Jupyter tree. What can be the problem?

**Answer**: You missed the path for the notebook (say, notebook_to_open.ipynb).
Try again with command like this:

(windows)

```
jupyter notebook c:/path/to/your/notebook_to_open.ipynb
```

(linux)

```
jupyter notebook ~/path/to/your/notebook_to_open.ipynb
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it run than just open?

Comment: @vevekseetharaman Please ask as a new question, many people will see and help answer.

Comment: have done it here @swatchai, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62674622/able-to-open-a-specific-jupyter-notebook-from-command-line-but-not-able-to-execu