# Able to open a specific jupyter notebook from command line but not able to execute

Tags: cmd, vbscript, jupyter-notebook

Am trying to open and execute .ipynb file from command line, i created a vb script for this. It is below.

```
Set WinScriptHost = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WinScriptHost.Run "C:\Users\vevek.seetharaman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat & jupyter notebook C:\Users\vevek.seetharaman\Downloads\Notebooks\MouseMovements.ipynb --notebook-dir=C:\Users\vevek.seetharaman\Downloads\ScriptAutomation\Notebooks", 1
Set WinScriptHost = Nothing
```

Mouse Movements.py is the name of the file i would like to open. When i execute this file, it opens the ipynb in browser just as expected.

However, the file just opens but does not execute. How can i execute along with open?

Comment: By deleting the previous question instead of editing it you've lost all the comments that people left trying to help you.

Comment: part of the question got solved. so changed to reflect what was left. Moreover, the question was marked "closed" by the moderator

Comment: Hmm, ["closure"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) doesn't mean the question was completed it means it was missing something to be a suitable question on [so]. If you had read the notice the closure produces you would see it directs you to [edit] the question to either provide more detail or to clear up any ambiguities that may be present. It's not a green light to go ask the same question again.

Comment: Thanks for your input, i thought instead of showing unnecessary inputs, just show the crux of the problem in another question. Apologies for inconvenience